# Easiest way to update items in a c# list

Tags: c#, list

I want to update a c# boolean list that is already existing.

Does below work?

```
myList.ForEach(item => item = true);
```

why do I see a context warning that

> The value passed to the method is never used because it is overwritten in the method body before being read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have as `item` is actually just a parameter for a lambda function. If you assign it, you are only modifying the parameter, not the value in the list. It's a valid thing to do, but it's not usually sensible, thus the warning.

If you want to actually update the values in the list, you need to do something like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < myList.Length; i++)
    myList[i] = true;
```

Looks more verbose? It is. But iterators aren't designed for mutation. If you are okay with generating a new list and replacing `myList` entirely, then you can just do:

```
myList = myList.Select(item => true).ToList();
```

Note that the original list will be gone.

Comment: So, is there no option to pass the parameter by reference?

Comment: @sgowd: it's technically possible, but for this particular case, I don't think it's worth it at all. To be honest, I think `ForEach()` is a bit of anti-pattern. Just use a `foreach` loop. LINQ is only useful for pipelines of transformations of data, not a way to do shorthand imperative code.